# Sudo yum vs sudo apt-get

Tags: linux, yum, apt-get

I used to be an Ubuntu user and recently installed Fedora on an old computer and I had to use yum instead of apt-get.
What is the difference between yum and apt-get?
Are there any benefits or drawbacks that differentiate one from the other?

Comment: Fedora installation is currently based on RPM packages, with yum (and dnf in the future). Debian variants (as Ubuntu) use .deb packages with their set of tools (dpkg, apt-get...). You cannot choose or change the package manager for each system.

Comment: Yes but what are the actual differences between yum and apt-get?

Comment: The fundamental difference is that they are designed to work with one or the other package type.  It would be similar to asking about the difference between an image viewer program designed to display just jpg images vs. one design to display just gif.  Do you mean what is the difference in features/commandset or some other aspect?

Comment: Features, commandset and benefits drawbacks